# Why do we need to give executable permission using chmod while running Perl script but no such thing is done while running the c program?

Tags: c, perl, chmod

chmod 777 script.pl is used when we run the script in the terminal.
But why we do not use chmod pg.c when we run the c program

Comment: The C program already has executable permission?

Comment: Because we do not run the `pg.c` program but the compiled version of it, e.g. `a.out`. And that `a.out` (usually) _does_ have the `x` flags set.

Comment: Don't use 777 - that gives every user account on the computer write access to your script. A more conservative choice would be 755.

Answer (score 4):

A C program is usually not executed directly but compiled into an executable file. The compiler sets the permissions on that file so that it can be executed directly.

Note that the executable flag is not necessary to run a script when explicitly invoking the interpreter. Running `perl script.pl` always works, similar to how `gcc pg.c` always works. The executable flag is only needed when the script is run without an explicit interpreter, i.e. as `./script.pl`. The operating system will then determine the correct interpreter from the file itself (e.g. from the `#!/usr/bin/perl` line).

Answer (score 0):

When you compiled c program it already gives you executable binary to use. But in case of Perl being a interpreted language you no need to compile it first, you can directly execute. Because of the +x permission is required.